# Incompatible shapes: [128,1] vs. [128,3,3]

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN to classify the SVHN dataset but run into an incompatible shape error when creating my model: Incompatible shapes: [128,3,3,10] vs. [128,1]. How do I fix it?

```
         model = Sequential([
                          Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32,3 
                           name='conv_1'),
                            
                           Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                          activation='relu', padding= 'SAME',  
                                   `name='conv_2'),
                           MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), name='pool_1'),
                            Dense(64,  kernel_regularizer = 
                            regularizers.l2(0.5),bias_initializer='ones',
                            activation='relu' , name='dense_1'),
                            Dropout(0.3),  
                            Dense(64,kernel_regularizer = 
                            regularizers.l2(0.5) , activation='relu' 
                           ,name='dense_2'),
                            BatchNormalization(),  
                            Dense(64,  kernel_regularizer = 
                            regularizers.l2(0.5) ,  activation='relu' 
                             ,name='dense_3'),
                             Dense(10,  activation='softmax' 
                             ,name='dense_4')
             ])


           model.compile(
           optimizer = 'adam',
           loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
           metrics= ['accuracy' ])
   

           history = model.fit(train_images,train_labels , epochs = 30 
           ,validation_split = 0.15,
                batch_size= 128, verbose = False )
```

Comment: Can you put the whole traceback?

Comment: Hi Pygril ,I tried to add the whole traceback here , but it say me  it so long

Answer (score 1):

Put a `Flatten` layer before the last `Dense` layer. Because you are not doing that, that is why the tensor is not reduced to a single dimension tensor before the layer that gives you the class.

It is a general pattern in TensorFlow to use a `Flatten` before the layer that outputs that class.

Also, I have removed the `BatchNormalization` in the random dense layer you had put, `BatchNormalization` layer is put generally after a Conv layer, you can put them after a `Dense` layer, though. If you are BatchNormalization, make sure the whole network or the relevant has it. Don't just put one random `BatchNormalization` layer.

Here's how you change your code to do that.

```
 model = Sequential([Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32,3), 
                           name='conv_1'),
                     BatchNormalization(),
                     Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                          activation='relu', padding= 'SAME',  
                          name='conv_2'),
                     BatchNormalization(),
                     MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), name='pool_1'),
                     Flatten(),
                     Dense(64,  kernel_regularizer = 
                           regularizers.l2(0.5), bias_initializer='ones',
                           activation='relu' , name='dense_1'),
                     Dropout(0.3),  
                     Dense(64,kernel_regularizer = 
                           regularizers.l2(0.5) , activation='relu', 
                           name='dense_2'),
                     Dense(64,  kernel_regularizer = 
                           regularizers.l2(0.5) ,  activation='relu', 
                           name='dense_3'),
                     Dense(10,  activation='softmax', 
                           name='dense_4')
             ])


           model.compile(
           optimizer = 'adam',
           loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
           metrics= ['accuracy' ])
   

           history = model.fit(train_images,train_labels , epochs = 30)
```

Comment: Thank you  Abhishek for your help , I tried to add a Flatten layer I got the error : Error when checking input: expected conv_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 32, 32)

Comment: Did you add at the same place I have added?

Comment: yes  Abhishek  I added the Flatten layer in the same place , I got  a new error Error when checking input: expected conv_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 32, 32

Comment: show me how you are sending data inside the network. that's where the problem can be then.

Comment: Thank you   Abhishek , I copied your code , I try to run it I told you the result   , this is how i send the data iside the network ,                                                                     
          history = model.fit(train_images,train_labels , epochs = 30 ,validation_split = 0.15,
                    callbacks=callbacks ,batch_size= 128, verbose = False )

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for your help, Finally, it works, it seems that the problem was in  the way that I put the layers,

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems in your code.

At first, please check the shape of `train_labels`.
`Incompatible shapes` error would appear if the shapes of tensor are wrong. I think that shape of `[128, 1]` means that the `train_label` is not kind of one-hot vector. If train_label shapes are such as [1, 3, 8, ..], then you should change the shapes into `[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ...]`

Second, you should add `Flatten` layer before `Dense` layer as mentioned above.

```
 model = Sequential([
       Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), name='conv_1'),
       ...
       MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), name='pool_1'),
       
       Flatten(),

       Dense(64,  kernel_regularizer ...
             ])
```

---

The shape of `(32, 32, 1)` means that the last dim of input shape should be one. so you should change the input_shape of `Conv2D` into `(32, 32, 1)`

```
Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 1) ...
```

Also, the train_images should be also changed into `(32, 32, 1)` because the channel of images is one.

```
train_images = tf.expand_dims(train_images, -1)
```

Additionally, you can get one-hot vector of `train_labels` like that:

```
train_labels = tf.squeeze(train_labels)
train_labels = tf.one_hot(train_labels, depth=10)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Gi, the shape of   train_labels is  (73257, 1) and the shape of train_images is  (73257, 32, 32), and the    train_labels are Under the form:   array([[1], [9], [2],.... [6], [1]], I tried to add a Flatten layer I got the error :   Error when checking input: expected conv_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 32, 32)

Comment: The shape of train_images of (73257, 32 ,32) means that the last dimension in input shape of the model should be 1.